# How can I set a variable to be the output of cat command?

Tags: bash, unix, cat

I have a file named "myout" in my current directory.
I wish to set the variable x to be the output of that line:

```
cat myout | cut -d" " -f1 | cut -d"/" -f1
```

I searched all over the site and couldn't find an answer,
any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
x=$(cut -d" " -f1 ./myout |  cut -d "/" -f1)
```

Updated as per Cyrus's comment.

Comment: or `x=$(cut -d" " -f1 ./myout |  cut -d "/" -f1)`

Comment: Yes even better to avoid the useless `cat ./myout`.